# Multiple file upload with different mimetype in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I have a problem regarding handling multiple file uploads with different mimetypes with Laravel.
In my form I have:

- file input for the cover image (accepts ONE image file)
- file input for image gallery (accepts MULTIPLE image files)
- file input for documents (accepts MULTIPLE documents files)

For the first two cases, I can handle them using a custom request class as mentionned [here](http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/).

What should I do add to handle the documents upload? Should I process the field normally in the controller? Or should I add another method to the custom request class to handle it separately?